# How to use sbin command in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

I need to use mkfs.vfat in Makefile mymake.mk,
but this command is locate in /sbin/

```
$ which mkfs.vfat
/sbin/mkfs.vfat
```

current user is not root, and I build my project then got error "command not found".

How to use sbin command in Makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is probably these two points:

1. The current user does not have `/sbin/` in his `$PATH`.
2. The current user is not allowed to write to the block device to create a file system on it.

The first problem is easily amended by just writing the full path instead of just the command in the Makefile:

```
target: sources …
        /sbin/mkfs.vfat ……
```

The second problem only occurs if you really want to write to a block device you haven't write permissions to.  In this case consider what you are doing.  Does it really make sense?  Typically this makes only sense in a `make install` situation, and this should be executed by user `root` only, so then you'd *have* write permissions.  In practice, one typically types `sudo make install` to gain root access for that installation step only.

If, however, this is a special case, then you can add that `sudo` to your Makefile as well:

```
target: sources …
        sudo /sbin/mkfs.vfat ……
```

(This would lead to being asked for the password when running the Makefile.)

And, last not least, you can use that `mkfs` to create a file, containing the newly created file system.  In that case you don't need any special permissions (besides write permissions to that file you want to create:

```
target: sources …
        /sbin/mkfs.vfat -C /path/to/my/filesystem ……
```

Answer (score 1):

Have somewhere in the header

```
PATH:=$(PATH):/sbin
```

Comment: Seems like this may only be the solution in certain contexts.  You may want to elaborate